# How to get network adapter name from IP in C?

Tags: windows-xp, libpcap, winpcap

I'm trying to capture packets in windows through WinPcap, by passing a proper network adapter name. In relation to this I want to know: Is there any simple way to get the network-adapter-name by just passing the IP address of the machine. I'm trying to get the network-adapter-name from IP (to make sure I'm using the right interface to capture packets using WinPcap out of many available in a Windows system, like wireless, VPN, LANs etc) which I think looks something like: 
     \Device\NPF_{5D24AE04-C486-4A96-83FB-8B5EC6C7F430}
Just the numeric representation should be enough. This is the exact parameter we've to pass to the method pcap_open() in WinPcap/Libpcap to start capturing packets.

I'm going through the sample codes for WinPcap at:

[Sample code 1](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_41b5/html/group__wpcap__tut1.html)
[Sample code 2](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcapsamps.html)

Comment: I was just trying to google around and found something related at the below link. I'm not able to understand the things there, though: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/05970282-5d63-4946-8c5c-19b0dbcbcbc8

Answer (score 0):

[Obtaining the device list](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut1.html), from the WinPcap 4.1.2 documentation.  The URL, unfortunately, will probably change if a new WinPcap release comes out; see [the WinPcap documentation page](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/default.htm) for a link to the current documentation, and look for the WinPcap tutorial.

Comment: can you please fix the URL, as trying to open it gave me 404 error. Appreciate your help.